# Flush make my PHP script to stop

Tags: php, file-io, flush

I've a piece of code which force a `php` page to `download` a file hosted on the server. Now the problem is after the piece of code if we written any other php code, Its not executing.

```
<?php
    $file = "http://some_server/downloads/file_to_download.pdf";

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    // flush();
    readfile($file);

    $var = "This is a variable";
    echo "Hello test. ".$var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this ! I just paste the above `piece of code` at the bottom its just worked !!!